# ui-router resolve undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I am not able to get the data from resolve in ui-router, its giving me `undefined`, below is my code

**Controller**

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('PostController', PostController);

/** @ngInject */
function PostController(questionData) {
    var vm = this;
        vm.post = questionData;
        console.log("Post Data in Ctrl", questionData);
}
```

**Factory**

I have a Cached list of post in `bootData`, first I check if post with `id` is in cached array, if found return the post `Object`,  if not make the request and return the promise.

```
function postService(dataService, $filter, $q) {

    return {
        post : post
    }

    // Cached promise of posts
    var bootData = dataService.boot();

    function post(id) {
        bootData.success(function(res){

                var postList = res.featured.posts.data;
                var post = $filter('filter')(postList, {id: id})[0];

                // Check if post with id found return it
                if (post && post.id > 0) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(post);
                    return deferred.promise;

                } else {
                    // Make request to api and return promise
                    return dataService.get('questions/' + id);
                }
        });
     }
}
```

**Route**

```
resolve: {
           // Check for logged in 
           loginRequired: function(auth){
              return auth.loginRequired();
         },
           postData: function(postService, $stateParams) {
              return postService.post($stateParams.id);
         }
}
```

I am stuck here, I thing there something wrong in factory method `post(id)`. Please help

Comment: try to return bootData.success from your post method then check for data

Comment: plz update controller code.

Comment: factory is giving me the post, i can see post object by logging below this `if (post && post.id > 0) {` conditional, my controller only taking `postData` and assigning it to scope `vm.post`, its returning undefined `console.log("Post Data in Ctrl", postData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning nothing (equivalent to `undefined`) from `postService.post` method. Instead make sure you return promise object `return bootData.success`:

```
function post(id) {
    return bootData.success(function(res) {

            var postList = res.featured.posts.data;
            var post = $filter('filter')(postList, {id: id})[0];

            // Check if post with id found return it
            if (post && post.id > 0) {
                return $q.when(post);
            } else {
                // Make request to api and return promise
                return dataService.get('questions/' + id);
            }
    });
 }
```

Also, avoid using deferred object, in your case you need `$q.when`.

Comment: now its returning whole `bootData` object, I just wanted the single `post`, How I can return only one `post`?

Comment: Check your logic, filtering part looks correct. Make sure `dataService.get('questions/' + id)` returns single post.

Comment: i want only single `post` if its cached else single post from server, and ya api is `dataService.get('questions/' + id)` returning single. currently its returning all thing

Comment: So debug it, I indicated you main problem, the rest of your code seems okay. It's something on your end.